# subprocess is not working while reading pipe

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating and using the QGIS tool PlugIn myself.

In conclusion, the plugin needs logic to ensure that the user has Java installed.

So I try to run java -version and pass the output when it comes out.

However, the Java version is not printed.

It is my source.

```
try:
    check_process = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version", "2>&1"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    check_process = check_process.communicate()

    # this is print func
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(check_process), tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)

except Exception as e:
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(e), tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
    return
```

and result is

```
2018-09-21T09:36:21 0   (None, '')
```

If you have any idea, I would appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Note: `"2>&1"` does nothing in your case. `Popen` does not interpret shell syntax if you do not specify `shell=True`. If you want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, if you want to redirect `stdout` to `stderr` use `stdout=subprocess.STDERR, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`. Note: if you want to use `shell=True`: 1) don't, it's a security issue 2) the argument should be a string not a list `Popen("java -version 2>&1", shell=True)` (NOT RECOMMENDED).

Comment: Try with `pexpect` library. It is much simpler.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta `shell=True` is a security issue in the same way as sql injection is. As long as there are no moving parts, as variables in the expression, or other means to modify it, it is not an issue. However, there is still an overhead in that the system will open an extra subprocess; it will open a shell process that will then execute the process you want, i.e., `java` in this case.

Comment: @JohanL Your are wrong. Never heard of SHELLSHOCK? It made **all** uses of shell vulnerable, even when the command was a fixed string. Sure, new systems should be fixed (but keep in mind that *tons* of systems are outdated or not patched properly) and it still requires some special conditions to do, but it's not true that `shell=True` is a security issue "like SQLi". It's strictly worse. Hence you should avoid it at all costs until you have to, and if you use `shell=True` you should really also use `env=` and keep only that stuff in the env that you know are needed.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta While I fully agree with not using `shell=True` and that the implications are worse, the security issue itself, is still of the same type as for SQL injections. However, I agree that the implications can be worse, specifically due to the SHELLSHOCK (that I actually hadn't heard of) and that it is generally better not to use `shell=True`. However, just simply state that using it is dangerous and should be avoided at all cost, without saying why, does not help the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: subprocess is not working

You are using `2>&1`, this is as **Shell command** and will not work until you use `shell=True`.
You are right to, redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, as `java -version` will write to `stderr`.
Do this for example: (**Note the diffs, no list and stdout=, to yours!**)

```
check_process = subprocess.Popen("java -version 2>&1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

As this will get the expected output for me, you get `(None, '')` using:

```
check_process = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version", "2>&1"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The first tuple is the output of `stdout` which is not used in `Popen`.
The second tuple is the output of `stderr` which is empty string.

For testing purpose try inside `QGIS`:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
print(result)
```

Comment: Forgive me for being late. It is too late to spend Korean holidays.

I ran it according to the example you provided, but it does not work.

`with subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:`

and result is `2018-09-28T09:24:00 0 Error : __exit__`


It works well when I run java -version directly from cmd, but I do not know the solution because it seems to apply differently to the QGIS environment I do not know.

Comment: The error inidcates you are using Python 2.x . The `supprocess` modul is different. I have rewriten my Answert as to wrong conclusions and Python Version 2.x.